# (UnicodeEncodeError): 'ascii' codec can not encode character u '\ xa 0' in position 0: ordinal not in range (128)"

Tags: encoding, google-cloud-ml

I followed the Training Quickstart of Cloud Machine learning(in the Google Cloud Platform Cloud Machine Learning ), but in the item on "Train on the cloud: single worker" I got following error.

```
Welcome to Cloud Shell! Type "help" to get started.
dzf044@machine:~$ cd ~/google-cloud-ml/samples/mnist/trainable/
dzf044@machine:~/google-cloud-ml/samples/mnist/trainable$JOB_NAME=mnist_${USER}_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
dzf044@machine:~/google-cloud-ml/samples/mnist/trainable$PROJECT_ID=`gcloud config list project --format "value(core.project)"`
our active configuration is: [cloudshell-XXXXXX]

dzf044@machine:~/google-cloud-ml/samples/mnist/trainable$TRAIN_BUCKET=gs://machine-xxxxx-ml
dzf044@machine:~/google-cloud-ml/samples/mnist/trainable$ TRAIN_PATH=${TRAIN_BUCKET}/${JOB_NAME}
dzf044@machine:~/google-cloud-ml/samples/mnist/trainable$ gsutil rm -rf ${TRAIN_PATH}

CommandException: 1 files/objects could not be removed.
dzf044@machine:~/google-cloud-ml/samples/mnist/trainable$ gcloud beta ml jobs submit training ${JOB_NAME} \

>   --package-path=trainer \
>   --module-name=trainer.task \
>   --staging-bucket="gs://machine-xxxxx-ml"\
>   --region=asia-northeast1 \
>   -- \
>   --train_dir="${TRAIN_PATH}/train"
>
```

> ERROR: gcloud crashed (UnicodeEncodeError): 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like something attempted to encode a non-breaking space (U+00A0) using ASCII. The problem is that the ASCII character set does not include that character.

Comment: I entered the last command by copying and pasting from the site, but I typed it again and entered it and solved the problem. It seems to be an error caused by no breaking space as you mentioned. Thank you very much.

Comment: File a bug at https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/entry

Comment: I filed.(https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=1423).